# Why doesn't template argument deduction work for this example (from A Tour of C++, 6.2.3 Template Argument Deduction)?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

The following example is copied from the book A Tour of C++ (6.2.3 Template Argument Deduction).

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(int);
    Vector(initializer_list<T>); //initializer-list constructor
    //...
};
Vector<int> v3(1); //here we need to be explicit about the element type (no element type is mentioned)
```

If you use `Vector v3(1)` instead you get the following compilation errors (MSVC2019, with /std:c++latest):

```
 - E0289: no instance of constructor "Vector" matches the argument list.
 - C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'Vector'.
 - C2783: 'Vector<T> Vector(int)': could not deduce template arguments for 'T'
 - C2784: 'Vector<T> Vector(Vector<T>)': could not deduce template arguments for 'Vector<T>' from 'int'.
 - ...
```

I don't understand why that `no element type is mentioned` part is relevant here. If you write `auto i(1);`, no element type is mentioned either but `i`'s type is set to `int`. In `Vector v3(1);` why can't the compiler also go and use `Vector(int)` constructor?

Comment: Yes, but _which_ `Vector<T>`'s `Vector(int)` constructor should it use?

Comment: Are you assuming it should guess `Vector<int>`? But `Vector<T>` for _every other `T`_ has the same constructor ...

Comment: @NathanOliver no, not a typo. It's like that in the book.

Comment: @Barry there are only 2 constructors, one is receiving an `int` and the other one an `initializer_list<T>`. I was expecting `Vector(int)` to be matched.

Comment: @Useless yes, I would expect the compiler to match `T` for `int` in this case.

Comment: But the constructor doesn't mention `T`. There is no relationship between the template type parameter and the constructor argument list. The first constructor for every possible `T` always takes an `int`, so it doesn't tell us anything about what type to choose for `T`. The `initializer_list` overload mentions `T`, which is why you can figure out what `T` should be when you match that constructor.

Comment: I've retracted my close vote.  The book does have the typo in it and stroustrup doesn't have any errata on it/

Comment: @Useless OK, I see your point now, and @Barry's. All template instantiations would have a `Vector(int)` but we need more information in order to choose which of those template instantiations we want to use.

Comment: @NathanOliver the example may be a bit inappropriate. It doesn't fit very much with how things are so easily and well explained in the rest of the book, at least until that point. And it makes you think there may be a typo.

Comment: @NathanOliver How is this a typo? This is what `std::vector` looks like - and the comment makes it clear that you have to explicitly provide `<int>`.

Comment: @Barry `std::vector` has a constructor like `vector(int)`?  No, it `vector(T)` for it to work.  Like I said in my later comment, I retracted that since this is a mistake that is in the book.

Comment: @NathanOliver [It has `vector(size_t)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector), #3 and #4. On the other hand, it _does not_ have `vector(T)`.